# Enabling binary media types breaks Option POST call (CORS) in AWS Lambda

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, microservices

New to AWS..

We have a .NET Core Microservice running on a serverless aws instance as lambda functions.

Our Controller looks like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SomeController : ControllerBase
    {


        [HttpGet()]
        [Route("getsomedoc")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomeDoc()
        {
            byte[] content;

            //UI needs this to process the document
            var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            contentDisposition.FileName = "File Name";

            Response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = contentDisposition.ToString();

            return File(content, "application/octet-stream");
        }


        [HttpPost()]
        [Route("somepost")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SomePost()
        {
            return null;

        }
    }
```

URL's

```
{{URL}}/getsomedoc
{{URL}}/somepost
```

We have enabled 'Binary Media Types' in AWS package settings to */* for the getsomedoc to work otherwise it was returning the byte array back instead of the file.

But this is breaking our '**somepost**' call when UI is accessing the API using 
Method: OPTIONS & Access-Control-Request-Method as POST

When we remove the binary media type the '**somepost**' starts working.

Looking for suggestions as why this might be happening? and what can we add/remove from gateway to get this fixed.

Comment: Please share the detailed error or warning message that you got about CORS issue while you make 'somepost' call.

Comment: In Postman, all we get is a 500 back ‘internal server error’ and in response headers, the access control headers stops coming in.

Comment: Lambda dumps the logs in cloud watch. Did you check the logs ?

Comment: Yes.. we did..though nothing is there that provides additional details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we ended up resolving this in a strange way.

Added two gateways for the lambda
- on one of them have binary enabled
- Disabled on the other one.

For
getsomedoc - Using the one where binary media types are enabled
postsomedoc - Using the other one

Wish there was a better way!!

Answer (score 1):

I have found this same behavior with my API. While looking everywhere for some help, I found a few things that address the issue:

Basically, [this bug report](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/7243) says the problem is having CORS enabled while also using the generic Binary Media Type `"*/*"`. Apparently the OPTIONS method gets confused by this. They discuss this in terms of using Serverless, but it should apply to using the console or other ways of interacting with AWS.

They link to [a possible solution](https://github.com/duro/serverless-binary-cors): you can modify the Integration Response of the OPTIONS method - change the Mapping Template's Content-Type to an actual binary media type, like `image/jpeg`. They say this allows you to leave the binary media type in Settings as `"*/*"`. This is a little hacky, but at least it is something.

There also was [this alternate suggestion](https://github.com/duro/serverless-binary-cors/issues/2) in the issues section of this GitHub repo that is a little less hacky. You can set the content handling parameter of the OPTIONS Integration Request to "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"... but you can only do this via CloudFormation or the CLI (not via the console). This is also [the recommended solution by some AWS Technicians](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=256140).

Answer (score 1):

Another possible workaround is to setup a custom Lambda function to handle the OPTIONS request, this way the API gateway may have the `"*/*"` Binary Media Type.

1. Create a new lambda function for handling OPTIONS requests:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers:{
          'access-control-allow-origin':'*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'access-control-allow-origin, content-type, access-control-allow-methods',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':"GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify("OK")
    };
    return response;
};
```

2. In your API Gateway OPTION method, change the integration type from Mock to Lambda Function.
3. Make sure to check 'Use Lambda proxy integration'
4. Select the correct region and point to the created Lambda Function

This way any OPTIONS request made from the browser will trigger the Lambda function and return the custom response.

Be aware this solution might involve costs.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the API to which we wanted to add an endpoint to retrieve an image, was internal, but very critical. It already had several other endpoints that were in use by many clients (both from the browser and from back-end workloads).

What we ended up doing is that we set the Binary Media Types to **image/*** .
The caveat here is that the clients making a call to this endpoint, will need to provide the **Accept** header, and set the value to **image/jpeg**.

Additionally, also added an **Integration Response** with the Content Handling attribute set to: **CONVERT_TO_BINARY**

This does not break the OPTIONS call for other endpoints **and** provides the clients a way to retrieve the image as well. This is something we and the clients, were ready to live with. I would recommend updating your documentation to let the clients know about the **Accept** header requirement.